# How to compare a hashSet within a foreach loop iterating through another hashSet Java

Tags: java, collections, foreach, conceptual

I'm running a test to see if the values I've inputed into a file are the same values I generate from my API. So I have actual values which are generated from my API and I have another list of expected values. The problem I have is that I am not able to make apple to apple comparisons.

Example:

```
Actual = {red, bleu, yellow, purple}
expected = {bleu, red, purple, yellow}

failure: red != bleu, bleu != red, yellow != purple, purple != yellow
```

I'm not sure how else to better describe what I'm saying other than showing you my code.

**Here is my code:**

```
TreeSet<String> hashSet = (TreeSet<String>) calcGraph.getInputs();
boolean success = true;
String error="";

for(String xpath : hashSet) {

    String actual = someApi(response, expression, xpath);

    for ( String values : data.getDataOutputs().keySet() ) {
        String expected = data.getDataOutputs().get(expectedXpath);

        if ( !expected.equals(actual)) {
            error+= "\nExpected : " + expected +"\nActual: " +actual+"\n";
            success = false;
        } if ( !success ) Assert.fail(error);

    }
}
```

How can I compare these lists within 1 foreach loop or equivalent? Any help or assistance would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
            Iterator<String> expectation = expectedList.iterator();
            Iterator<String> actuation = actualList.iterator();

            while((expectation.hasNext()) && (actuation.hasNext())) {

                String exp = expectation.next();
                String act = actuation.next();

                logger.info("Expected: "+exp);
                logger.info("Actual: "+act);

                // Validation check
                if ( !exp.equals(act)) {
                    error+= "\nExpected : " + exp +"\nActual: " +act+"\n";
                    success = false;
                } if ( !success ) Assert.fail(error);
            }
```

Order matters, so this will fail...

Comment: for-each is not the guy for this job. You need an ordinary for loop.

Comment: I don't see any List here. I see a `hashSet` variable (which implies a `HashSet`) and a `Map` (`data.getExplanationOutputs()`). Which lists are you trying to compare?

Comment: You want to use assertj; it has assertions for cases like these (`assertThat(list1).containsExactlyElementsOf(list2)`).

Comment: Arraylist and a for-loop with counter might be what you need!

Comment: If you just want to know if two sets have the same elements, just use `set1.equals(set2)`.

Comment: @Eran however that will not take the iteration order into account...

Comment: @fge We don't know which Map implementation the OP is using, but if it's not ordered, the iteration order over its keySet is already meaningless.

Comment: @Eran as I see a `TreeSet` in the code, my guess is that iteration order matters here; I may be wrong, of course

Comment: @Eran I'd like to structure of my comparisons the same, I'd just like to know a mechanism in which I can have both expected and actual. Currently actual is within a foreach loop where it loops through an entire list before iteratering through the next element in the outter foreach loop.

Comment: @fge yes the order matters, that's the problem I'm having

Comment: Then don't bother and just use assertj.

Comment: where would i put an assertj assertion? I would be having the same problem regardless how I do my assertion where it's a pretty library or plain old java

Comment: @Eran that won't work, the problem I have is order...that's why I was thinking we find a way to do assertions within the foreach loop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use

```
Set.contains(value)
```

to check if an actual value is in expected value, you only need one for loop to achieve this

See this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Thanks I restructured my code a little and used contains

Answer (score 0):

The question is just so weird.  In the title you said `HashSet` vs `HashSet` comparison, and in the content you are using `TreeSet`.

From the question, it seems that you have a `Set` of actual results, and you want to compare against a `Set` of expected result, regardless of the iteration order, am I right?

Using `contains` is surely wrong, as well as using iterator to do comparison.

The solution is in fact straight-forward.  From javadoc of `Set`:

> boolean equals(Object o)
>
> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true
>   if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same
>   size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set
>   (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the
>   specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works
>   properly across different implementations of the set interface.

What you need to do is simply

```
expectedResultSet.equals(actaulResultSet)
```